# How to create a pill rectangle using d3 custom symbol

Tags: d3.js

As D3 has limited symbols so I need a custom symbol for pill rectangle shape.

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#symbols,

> To implement a custom symbol type, pass an object that implements [symbolType.draw](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#symbolType_draw).

The `draw` function gets 2 arguments: the [CanvasPathMethods context](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#canvaspathmethods), and size (which represents the side measurement of a square that the symbol should be drawn in).  You can use any of the canvas path methods to specify a path, and the resulting symbol will work in both SVG and Canvas.

The path methods are:

```
void closePath();
void moveTo(unrestricted double x, unrestricted double y);
void lineTo(unrestricted double x, unrestricted double y);
void quadraticCurveTo(unrestricted double cpx, unrestricted double cpy, unrestricted double x, unrestricted double y);
void bezierCurveTo(unrestricted double cp1x, unrestricted double cp1y, unrestricted double cp2x, unrestricted double cp2y, unrestricted double x, unrestricted double y);
void arcTo(unrestricted double x1, unrestricted double y1, unrestricted double x2, unrestricted double y2, unrestricted double radius);
void rect(unrestricted double x, unrestricted double y, unrestricted double w, unrestricted double h);
void arc(unrestricted double x, unrestricted double y, unrestricted double radius, unrestricted double startAngle, unrestricted double endAngle, optional boolean counterclockwise = false);
```

For example, to create a rectangle symbol:

```js
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 100)

let drawCustomSymbol = (context, size) => {
  let top    = -size * 0.25
  let bottom = +size * 0.25
  let left   = -size / 2
  let right  = +size / 2
  context.moveTo(left, top)
  context.lineTo(right, top)
  context.lineTo(right, bottom)
  context.lineTo(left, bottom)
  context.closePath()
}

let customSymbol = d3.symbol().type({ draw: drawCustomSymbol })

svg.append("path")
  .attr("transform", "translate(25,25)")
  .attr("d", customSymbol.size(10))

svg.append("path")
  .attr("transform", "translate(50,25)")
  .attr("d", customSymbol.size(20))

svg.append("path")
  .attr("transform", "translate(100,25)")
  .attr("d", customSymbol.size(50))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

To create a pill shape, you could extend this by using `context.arcTo` for the ends instead.